# Spark Kafka streaming with minimum messages is already too much

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I'm using kafka spark streaming to receive heavy messages of 100MB over 48 partitions and 6 brokers.

I get about 100 messages in the queue per hour and I need about 5min to process them.

But when my program crash for whatever reason and is restarted after, let's say, one day, the queue contains 2400 messages, in other words, 240GB of messages.
Where 10GB is barely "processable", 240GB is just impossible.

So my goal was to limit the number of messages, I tried many things but the minimum I can get is 216 messages. Which is already too much.

This is what I tried :

```
    kafka = {
      bootstrap.servers = "10.111.212.186:9093"
      group.id = "BiloFTTB"
      key.deserializer = "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"
      value.deserializer = "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"
      auto.offset.reset = earliest
      security.protocol = SASL_PLAINTEXT
      sasl.mechanism = SCRAM-SHA-256
      isolation.level = read_uncommitted
      max.poll.records = 1 // works, but gives 216.
//fetch.max.bytes=2147483647 // max int, gives 0 records
//max.partition.fetch.bytes=200000000 // don't do anything
    }
    spark = {
      appname = "fftb_cmts_customer"
      spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled = true
      spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition = 1
      spark.ui.showConsoleProgress = false
      spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled = false
      spark.streaming.receiver.maxRate = 1
    }
    topic = "..."
    frequency = 240
```

I tried also backpressure with initialRate = 1, but it's the same as max.poll.records...
Do you have any idea of a setting or something else that I can try ?